# Swift UITabBarController hide with animation

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to add animation to my tabBarController when hidden. Im able to accomplish this effect with the `navigationBarController` by using `self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true`. I'm able to hide the tabBar by using `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true` but i do not get the animation how can I do this thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could change the tab bar's frame inside an animation, so something like:

```
func hideTabBar() {
    var frame = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame
    frame?.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height + (frame?.size.height)!
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame = frame!
    })
}

func showTabBar() {
    var frame = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame
    frame?.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - (frame?.size.height)!
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame = frame!
    })
}
```

Which sets the tab bar just below the visible screen, so that it slides up/down from the bottom.

Answer (score 12):

I've developed a util extension for UIViewController
**Swift 4** compatible:

```
extension UIViewController {

    func setTabBarHidden(_ hidden: Bool, animated: Bool = true, duration: TimeInterval = 0.3) {
        if animated {
            if let frame = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame {
                let factor: CGFloat = hidden ? 1 : -1
                let y = frame.origin.y + (frame.size.height * factor)
                UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
                    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame = CGRect(x: frame.origin.x, y: y, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
                })
                return
            }
        }
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = hidden
    }

}
```

Comment: on iPhone X , when tab bar is hidden there is a gray background of tab bar there.

Comment: @Alfi same here, did you fixed it?

Comment: @Mark Dylan B Mercado, Sure I fixed it but I don't remember how, Sorry I does't have access to that project right now to help you more.

Comment: This solution is not save if you can call hidden=true when it's already hidden. It will move the frame endlessly down.

Answer (score 5):

Improvement of the response of @Luca Davanzo. If the bar is already hidden, it will continue hiding it and moving it lower. Also get rid of the return, so the state of the tabbar.hidden changes when the animation happens.
So I added a check:

```
extension UIViewController {

func setTabBarHidden(_ hidden: Bool, animated: Bool = true, duration: TimeInterval = 0.5) {
    if self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden != hidden{
        if animated {
            //Show the tabbar before the animation in case it has to appear
            if (self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden)!{
                self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = hidden
            }
            if let frame = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame {
                let factor: CGFloat = hidden ? 1 : -1
                let y = frame.origin.y + (frame.size.height * factor)
                UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
                    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame = CGRect(x: frame.origin.x, y: y, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
                }) { (bool) in
                    //hide the tabbar after the animation in case ti has to be hidden
                    if (!(self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden)!){
                        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = hidden
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

In case if you need to toggle it from hide to visible and vice versa:

```
func toggleTabbar() {
    guard var frame = tabBarController?.tabBar.frame else { return }
    let hidden = frame.origin.y == view.frame.size.height
    frame.origin.y = hidden ? view.frame.size.height - frame.size.height : view.frame.size.height
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame = frame
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 solution:

```
tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
UIView.transition(with: tabBarController!.view, duration: 0.35, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple extension :

```
func setTabBar(hidden:Bool) {
    guard let frame = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame else {return }
    if hidden {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame = CGRect(x: frame.origin.x, y: frame.origin.y + frame.height, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
        })
    }else {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame = UITabBarController().tabBar.frame

        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. But when calling hidden = false when tab is not hidden, it makes jumpy animation

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick animation to show/hide from the bottom of the screen (tweak to your taste):

```
public extension UITabBar {
    func hideWithAnimation() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard !self.isHidden else { return }
            UIView.transition(with: self, duration: 0.2, options: .curveEaseIn,
                              animations: { () -> Void in
                self.frame.origin.y += self.frame.size.height
            }, completion: { _ in
                self.isHidden = true
            })
        }
    }

    func showWithAnimation() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard self.isHidden else { return }
            UIView.transition(with: self, duration: 0.15, options: .curveEaseOut,
                              animations: { () -> Void in
                self.isHidden = false
                self.frame.origin.y -= self.frame.size.height
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to use this from SwiftUI, you will have to use something like [SwiftUI-Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) to get the `UITabBarController`.

Note: I added `DispatchQueue.main.async` because it can be called from another thread in my case, you should check if you need it and remove it if not.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add UIView transitionWithView class func

**Swift 2**

```
func hideTabBarWithAnimation() -> () {
    UIView.transitionWithView(tableView, duration: 1.0, options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
func hideTabBarWithAnimation() -> () {
    UIView.transition(with: tableView, duration: 1.0, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: It's not Swift 3 compliant. "hidden" doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: fixed to swift 3

Answer (score -1):

So I've been playing around for 3 days with this now, finding out that the one that worked for me in my code was Adriana's post from 14th Sept 2018.  But I was not sure how to use the coding once copied into my Project. So, after much experimenting I found that the way I could use this func was to put the following into into the respective swipe actions.

```
setTabBarHidden(false)


setTabBarHidden(true)
```

My next step is to try to get the swipe actions working while using UIScrollView in the same UIView at the same time.