# How to have custom animation for hide tab bar

Tags: ios, swift

```
extension XXX: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationController.Operation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return Animator
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a custom push animation by implementing the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` as above, it works fine.

the only problem here is I set `toViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true`, the animation doesn't works very well with the `barBar`, it keeps using the default animation.

How can I have a custom animation for hiding the tabBar ?

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169966/swift-uitabbarcontroller-hide-with-animation

Comment: @NiravHathi the animation is fine, but the bottomLayoutGuide doesn't change, it means the bottom bar disappears, but the space is still there.